# $stateProvider redirecting to param based url instead of provided url in angularJs routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create routes in my angular app like:

- baseURL/123 (123 will be resolved using /:opportunityId param)
- baseURL/analysis (analysis is provided in the state URL)

I have tried with the code below to create it:

`$stateProvider
        .state('analysis', {
            url: '/analysis',
            controller: 'FileAnalysisController',
            template: fileAnalysisTemplate, 
            params: {
                data: "null"
            }
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/:opportunityId",
            controller: 'DashboardController',
            template: dashboardTemplate
        })`

But, when I am hitting the url like: 'baseURL/analysis', it is calling dashboard state. I don't know what exactly I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in route `baseURL/123` **123** can be anything, it can be number, text even object. So in your case when you are calling `baseURL/analysis` **analysis** is consider in `baseURL/:opportunityId` param and angular routes you to this route instead of what you have define.

To solve this solution us one more base path in  you route where you want to accept using URL param like:

Instead of **`baseURL/123`** use **`baseURL/xyz/123`** so that anything after `baseURL/` will be resolved as per route define.